# refactor a pythonic recursive filter for dict

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, refactoring

Now I have a piece of codes as follows:

```
def checker(dict_element, dict_filter):
    global counter
    counter = 0

    def fullfill_filter(key, value):
        if key in dict_filter:
            if value in dict_filter[key]:
                return True

    def extract_dict(dict_element):
        global counter

        for key, value in dict_element.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                if fullfill_filter(key, value):
                    counter += 1
            elif isinstance(value, dict): 
                extract_dict(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                extract_list(key, value)

    def extract_list(key, list_element):
        global counter

        for el in list_element:
            if isinstance(el, dict):
                extract_dict(el)
            if isinstance(el, list):
                extract_list(el)
            if isinstance(el, str):
                if fullfill_filter(key, el):
                    counter += 1

    extract_dict(dict_element)

    if counter == len(dict_filter.keys()):
        return True
    return False
```

It is used to filter a dictionary `dict_element` contains various types of object, and I want to find the right one according to what I have in the dict_filter.

For example I have a dictionary have two sub dictionary as follows:

```
list = [
    {
        'services': [],
        'location': {
            'latitude': '51.026',
            'country': 'Germany',
            'longitude': '13.725'
        },
        'available': 'true',
        'technologies': ['Virtual Machines', 'Distributed Systems', 'Internet', 'Wired'],
        'type': 'node',
        'exclusive': 'false',
        'types': [{
            'disk_images': [{
                'version': 'f22',
                'os': 'Linux',
                'name': 'Fedora f22'
            }],

        }]
    }, {
        'services': [],
        'location': {
            'latitude': 'unknown',
            'country': 'Taiwan',
            'longitude': 'unknown'
        },
        'available': 'false',
        'technologies': ['Virtual Machines', 'Distributed Systems', 'Internet',],
        'type': 'node',
        'exclusive': 'false',
        'types': [{
            'disk_images': [{
                'version': 'f24',
                'os': 'Linux',
                'name': 'Fedora f24'
            }],
        }]
    }
]
```

If I do as`[checker(dict, dict_filter = {'avaliable': 'true', 'country':'Germany'}) for dict in list]` 
or `[checker(dict, {'version': 'f22'}) for dict in list]`
or `[checkert(dict, {technologies: 'Wired'} for dict in list]`
, I can filter out the second case and get the first dict, However, as you can see the codes is ugly and badly naming(not a native English speaker), is there a better and cleaner way to refactor it in pythonic way?

Comment: Your dict example is not valid. Did you mean dict_element = [...] instead of {...}?

Comment: @ThomasChristensen sorry, now it should be fine